# Jquery data() returning undefined

Tags: jquery, jinja2

I have been doing a simple jquery data() test. However it is returning undefined. It works on jsfiddle though (http://jsfiddle.net/yrCdj/).

I have a jinja2 loop which populates a div and I want to tag it with some metadata for use later :

```
{% for s in siteInfo[:markers[0]] %}
<div class="sitebox2">
<script>
$(".sitebox2:last").append('<a href="/sites/d?siteid={{s[5]}}">{{s[0]}}</a><br>Distance                    from {{loc}} is {{s[6]}} km.<br>');
$(".sitebox2:last").data('fruit', 'apple');
</script>

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I then try to call this data to test if it is working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".sitebox2").each(function(k, v) {
    var f = $(v).data('fruit');
alert(f);
});

</script>
```

It returns undefined. Any ideas on what is going wrong? It looks like a problem of scope so perhaps I need to find a way to get the data directly from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try to excute the script after the close div tag.

```
{% for s in siteInfo[:markers[0]] %}
<div class="sitebox2">
  <a href="/sites/d?siteid={{s[5]}}">{{s[0]}}</a><br>Distance from {{loc}} is {{s[6]}} km.<br>
</div>
<script>
  $(".sitebox2:last").data('fruit', 'apple');
</script>
{% endfor %}
```

Or you could use `data` attribute like:

```
{% for s in siteInfo[:markers[0]] %}
<div class="sitebox2" data-fruit="apple">
  <a href="/sites/d?siteid={{s[5]}}">{{s[0]}}</a><br>Distance from {{loc}} is {{s[6]}} km.<br>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```